# Ошибка "Cannot set property of NULL"

Tags: javascript

До сегодняшнего дня ни разу не писал на чистом javascript'e. Но вот приспичило. У сразу же схлопотал ошибку, а что не так - не пойму.

Есть один файл (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="qwer">11</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

И второй файл (script.js):

```
(function () { 
document.getElementById("qwer").innerHTML='44';
})();
```

В общем скрипт не работает, отладчик пишет "uncaught typeerror: cannot set property of null"
Что же не так? Ведь элемент с id "qwer" существует.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В момент исполнения скрипта, документ еще не загрузился до конца.

Первый вариант. 
Вам нужно сделать аналог jquery метода $(document).ready().
Например, вызывать свой метод внутри window.onload = function(){};
Учтите, что таким образом функцию на событие можно навесить только один раз. Если мало - нужно сделать свой кроссбраузерный аналог jquery метода bind.

Есть второй вариант. Переместить вызов скрипта в самый низ документа.

Comment: Перемещение вниз <body> сработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("qwer").innerHTML='44';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно поставить в тег script defer)

Comment: Формально, решение корректное для современных браузеров, однако я бы не рекомендовал его так использовать. На мой взгляд, это свойства-украшалки, которые должны помогать оптимизации, а не влиять на логику исполнения.

Answer (score 1):

Просто переместите тег script в самый низ:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="qwer">11</div>
 </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```